# Install pypy on a virtual environnement with Anaconda

Tags: python, virtualenv, anaconda, pypy

I am trying to treat a massive load of data in order to do some data-mining with Python. I have heard of a optimized python implementation called Pypy. I am having trouble getting Pypy working.

**Environnement:** I am using Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit) on a Linux CentOS distribution.
According to the installation advice I had to use the portable version for this distribution. I tried to create an virtual environnement using virtualenv, which I install with Anaconda'a pip.

**Issue :** When trying to run Pypy I get the following result :

```
$ cd pypy_folder_root
$ virtualenv -p bin/pypy my_env
Running virtualenv with interpreter bin/pypy
debug: OperationError:
debug:  operror-type: LookupError
debug:  operror-value: no codec search functions registered: can't find encoding
debug: OperationError:
debug:  operror-type: AttributeError
debug:  operror-value: stdout
```

Maybe should I use the virtual environnements manager included in Anaconda (called conda). How can I create a new virtual env with Pypy as Python interpreter in it ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Which version of PyPy are you using exactly?

Comment: I'm using `pypy3 2.4 linux x86 64 portable`

Comment: We released a new PyPy3 version yesterday. It's an alpha version, but still it should work better than the old 2.4 version in most cases. I'm not sure, but I think this should solve the problem. A portable version will be released in the next few days.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer :)

Comment: A portable version of PyPy3.3 was released a few hours ago: https://github.com/squeaky-pl/portable-pypy

Comment: Thank you for the info ! But I don't understand how I am supposed to install Pypy on Anaconda...